# How to repeat rows of a table according to date gaps of each record?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a package journey history according to the recorded dates, however this table has gaps between the recorded dates. I would like to complete these gaps when the difference between the current date and the next date is greater than 1 day.

in the first ID_SHP the fact described above happens twice. Let's see:

| ID_SHP | EVENT_DATE | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 2022-10-31T15:26:02 | a_date_created |
| 1000 | 2022-10-31T15:29:40 | b_date_buff |
| 1000 | 2022-11-01T03:10:03 | c_date_hand |
| 1000 | 2022-11-01T03:10:03 | d_date_inv |
| 1000 | 2022-11-01T06:18:28 | e_date_rea_print |
| 1000 | 2022-11-01T06:18:54 | f_date_pri |
| 1000 | 2022-11-01T11:49:56 | h_date_dro |
| 1000 | 2022-11-03T13:15:01 | i_date_pic |

In the example above, we should have 3 more records. 1 between 10/31 and 11/01 and another between 11/01 and 11/03.

So, it should be correct:

| ID_SHP | EVENT_DATE | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 2022-10-31T15:26:02 | a_date_created |
| 1000 | 2022-10-31T15:29:40 | b_date_buff |
| 1000 | 2022-10-01T00:00:00 | b_date_buff |
| 1000 | 2022-11-01T03:10:03 | c_date_hand |
| 1000 | 2022-11-01T03:10:03 | d_date_inv |
| 1000 | 2022-11-01T06:18:28 | e_date_rea_print |
| 1000 | 2022-11-01T06:18:54 | f_date_pri |
| 1000 | 2022-11-01T11:49:56 | h_date_dro |
| 1000 | 2022-11-02T00:00:00 | h_date_dro |
| 1000 | 2022-11-03T00:00:00 | h_date_dro |
| 1000 | 2022-11-03T13:15:01 | i_date_pic |

Code for table:
`

```
WITH table AS
 (SELECT '10000' as SHP_ID,
  '2022-10-31T15:26:02' as Event_date,
  'a_date_created' as Status
  UNION ALL SELECT '10000', DATETIME '2022-10-31T15:29:40', 'b_date_buff'
  UNION ALL SELECT '10000', DATETIME '2022-11-01T03:10:03', 'c_date_hand'
  UNION ALL SELECT '10000', DATETIME '2022-11-01T03:10:03', 'd_date_inv'
  UNION ALL SELECT '10000', DATETIME '2022-11-01T06:18:28', 'e_date_rea_print'
  UNION ALL SELECT '10000', DATETIME '2022-11-01T06:18:54', 'f_date_pri'
  UNION ALL SELECT '10000', DATETIME '2022-11-01T11:49:56', 'h_date_dro'
  UNION ALL SELECT '10000', DATETIME '2022-11-03T13:15:01', 'i_date_pic'
  UNION ALL SELECT '20000', DATETIME '2022-12-16T14:52:55', 'a_date_created'
  UNION ALL SELECT '20000', DATETIME '2022-12-19T11:10:23', 'g_date_rea_pickup'
  UNION ALL SELECT '20000', DATETIME '2022-12-20T10:58:25', 'i_date_pic'
  )

SELECT *
FROM table
```

`

I tried, through the lag function, to find out what the next date was and to make the difference between them, but not from this point on, I can't repeat the dates I need as in the previous example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below approach

```
select * except(next_date, day) replace(
  if(date(event_date) = day, event_date, datetime(day)) as event_date)
from (
  select *, ifnull(lead(event_date) over(partition by shp_id order by event_date), event_date) next_date
  from table
), unnest(generate_date_array(date(event_date), date(next_date))) day
order by event_date
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mikhail. the code worked perfectly. I had to treat the table very nicely to produce the input result for your script. a perfect script!